# Which event raised when set value of input in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

When set value of input in JavaScript which event raised?
I tried these event: (`propertychange` `change` `keypress` `paste` `focus` `textInput` `input` `keyup` `keydown` `change`).
For example:

```
$('input').live/bind/on('which event', function() {
    //...
});
$('input')[0].value = "sd";
```

Comment: Are you perhaps looking for the `change` event?

Comment: Since you're doing it programatically, why not just run whatever function you need when setting the input's value?

Comment: No event is raised when you change the value programmatically (except `propertychange`, which is non-standard). Consider raising your own event after performing the change operation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you set the value programmatically no event will be raised. You can raise it yourself though:

```
$('input')[0].value = "sd";
$('input').first().trigger("change");
```

Or just using jQuery:

```
$('input').first().val("sd").trigger("change");
```

Comment: why you don't use just .change() function, such as answer of @Deepak Biswal

Comment: It's the same. The change function without arguments is just a shorthand for `.trigger("change")`. I think using trigger makes it clearer what's going on (the change event is triggered on the element), but you can use whichever you find easier to read.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this. You have to explicitly call `change` event.

```
$('input').val('New Value').change();
```

Answer (score 1):

When a value is changed via a script the change event is not fired, if you want to run a handler then you can trigger the event manually

```
$('input').eq(0).val("sd").trigger('change');
```