# When does DOM fire events?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

When typing into `<input>`, an `Event` is fired. However, when running `document.querySelector("input").value = "x"`, none is fired.

When clicking into `<details>`, an `Event` is fired. And when running `document.querySelector("details").open = true`, the event **is also** fired.

Is this pure inconsistency or was it the developers personal taste?

Or is there some deeper concept on when events are being fired and when not? Maybe even outside of HTML (on a more general computer science level)?

Background: I'm building a component library and try to be as close to native HTML as possible so that the consumers can feel at home.

Comment: When you set the value programmatically no event will be fired. To fire event manually, you can follow this https://stackoverflow.com/a/18465487/5882307

Comment: Does this answer your question? [which event raised when set value of input in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18465414/which-event-raised-when-set-value-of-input-in-javascript)

Comment: Please read my question carefully before requesting to close it and posting any links to other questions. Thanks.

Comment: For starters, *HTML* __never__ fires anything. The **DOM** does.

Comment: And, well, *it depends*. It depends on the events you're listening to, and what their documentation says about when they will or won't fire.

Comment: (Side note: you should be asking about DOM, not HTML) You should start by reading the W3C specifications. Then you can look at MDN for documentation of a real life implementation. Then there's this https://www.w3.org/2002/07/DOM-Level-3-Events-issues/issues.html

Comment: "HTML" was fine, some of the various events that are fired on an HTMLInputElement [are defined by HTML](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/input.html) (some others by [W3c input-events](https://w3c.github.io/input-events), for the *text* inputs.) If you want to be pedantic, then the UA does fire the event.

Comment: And you're right that this `toggle` event is a bit weird. I believe it's even unique in that regard. I can't find back the discussions that lead to this choice for the moment, but the whole API around `<details>` always sounded off to me... (If you really want to know, you may want to head to https://whatwg.org/chat you should be able to ask the ones that made the choice.)

Comment: I found https://github.com/whatwg/html/commit/899e6fad304e728090e9bcddfcefa51ab76e56f2 which leads to [this bug](https://www.w3.org/Bugs/Public/show_bug.cgi?id=22942) but it's rather poor in arguments...

Answer (score 2):

An Event is fired to notify the program of an [occurrence](https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#action-versus-occurance) they might want to interact on.

The `<input>` case seems quite straightforward here: when the user edits the input value, we want our JS to handle these changes, maybe even prevent them.
When our program did the change, e.g by setting the `.value` IDL attribute, it's far less interesting to have that notification, if we wanted to prevent the change, we wouldn't have done it to begin with.

This is the behavior of most "native" events.

Now, for the case of `<details>`'s *toggle* event, it's indeed weird to notify the program when it did the change. The thing is that we're in a very particular case where the user agent itself can change the attribute when the user toggles the element.

```css
details { color: blue }
details[open] { color: red } /* when the attribute is set */
```

```html
<details><summary>open me</summary>Now I'm red</details>
```

This is because the `open` attribute is [reflected](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/common-dom-interfaces.html#reflect) in IDL, i.e when you set the IDL attribute (`.open`), the attribute is either set or removed (because here it's a *boolean* attribute). And it was thought that this attribute would be used to help styling the element, so that we don't need yet another `:pseudo-class` with complicated relationships.

So we end up with an attribute that can be changed by the user, and we definitely want an event when the user does *this* change. So it makes *some* sense that this event actually represents the attribute change, and that even when we change it programmatically, we do have an event firing.

Honestly, I too find it particularly surprising. You can read [this very related thread](https://github.com/w3c/html/issues/600) on which I based most of this answer, where some arguments where exposed, in both ways, though not exactly about the event.

So I think that you can keep the mental model of "native" events firing when something outside our doing did happen, while remembering that there are always particular cases and that you should look at the details of each event.

Comment: You mentioned that "the specs discussion is actually openly accessible", you happen to know where?

Comment: Btw. I've followed your advice and asked in the WHATWG Chat
https://matrix.to/#/!AGetWbsMpFPdSgUrbs:matrix.org/$WWSdCnWP7lpaiW1l6y55jqkpPL_s6Oo_q8jGKGRnKlk?via=matrix.org&via=igalia.com&via=mozilla.org

Comment: @kraftwer1 https://github.com/whatwg/html/commit/899e6fad304e728090e9bcddfcefa51ab76e56f2 was one entry point for this particular case, one could try to find even prior threads about this, but it's so old you'd have to [dig the mailing lists](https://www.w3.org/Search/Mail/Public/). Some of the earliest mentions I got pointed to https://www.w3.org/WAI/PF/HTML/wiki/Details_element_as_a_replacement_for_summary_attribute%2C_Feb_15%2C_2010   I also linked to https://github.com/w3c/html/issues/600 which was opened after the facts, but which at least represents the current status.

Answer (score 0):

Events  (such as value changes) triggered by users and value changes done programmatically are different things. Thus, JS behaves differently. Such distinction gives developers more control of how the system behaves.

If you wish to trigger `change` event after updating the value, you need to do it yourself with `dispatchEvent()`.

The links below explain how JS events work. If you do the same for your library, you will have good compatibility.

https://www.w3docs.com/learn-javascript/introduction-to-browser-events.html
https://www.w3docs.com/snippets/javascript/how-to-create-and-trigger-event-in-javascript.html

Comment: Doesn't really explain why then doing `<details>.open = true` does fire an event.

Comment: Any answer to this would be opinionated unless someone has access to w3c standard discussion boards with this specific issue.

Comment: Fair enough, we've got a "Opinion-based" closure option if you think so. But that answer doesn't answer the question, and note that the specs discussion is actually openly accessible.

Comment: Thanks guys - I've asked in the WHAWG Chat, see https://app.element.io/#/room/#whatwg:matrix.org/$WWSdCnWP7lpaiW1l6y55jqkpPL_s6Oo_q8jGKGRnKlk